# Build is failing because of execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin

I have updated Kotlin library in  *build.gradle*  with  **implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version**   but still facing the problem, what is the root cause of this issue

[image: valid HTML]

More precisely i'm getting issue when i add  **implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.0.0"** this in  *build.gradle*

Comment: I think it's known error, remove all break points on the debugging

Comment: I haven't add any breakpoints @Log.d